# Product Price Not displayed for few Variation Products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In WordPress woo-commerce, I use only variation products. Variation is based on Color:

1. Starwhite
2. Ivory

On the single product page, **the price** for both the colors are displayed for few products and it is **Does NOT display** price for few other products, when I have mentioned it. How can i fix this ?

PHP Code:

```php
<?php if( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) ){ ?><p class="price"><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></p><?php } ?>
```

Image of Variation production (price Displayed)
[image]

Image of Variation Production (Price Not Displayed)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue myself,
First i had to define a new SKU for each product
Add Global Attributes to the product variation
and ensure, The variation color is selected for each variation